# Node.js background worker is not gracefully shutting down on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have the following node.js worker running on Heroku (simplified). It's running as a worker process using a `Procfile` on a single dyno. I am expecting it to gracefully shut down with an exit code of `0`. However, it always exits with an exit code of `1` and doesn't even execute the full shutdown function.

Heroku gives a process 30s to gracefully shut down (see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#shutdown).
Node version is `16.13.0`.

Locally it of course works like a charm.

Any help is highly appreciated.

```
let running = true;

(async function () {
  console.log('starting')
  while (running) {
    console.log('ping')
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))
  }
})()

process.on('SIGTERM', function () {
  console.log('received SIGTERM')
  console.log('shutting down')
  running = false
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('finished shutting down')
    process.exit(0)
  }, 1000)
})
```

Heroku logs:

```
2021-11-11T17:27:18.884817+00:00 heroku[test-worker.1]: Restarting
2021-11-11T17:27:18.935900+00:00 heroku[test-worker.1]: State changed from up to starting
2021-11-11T17:27:18.831078+00:00 app[test-worker.1]: ping
2021-11-11T17:27:19.594077+00:00 heroku[test-worker.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-11-11T17:27:19.654762+00:00 app[test-worker.1]: received SIGTERM
2021-11-11T17:27:19.654801+00:00 app[test-worker.1]: shutting down
2021-11-11T17:27:19.786370+00:00 heroku[test-worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-11-11T17:27:22.660423+00:00 heroku[test-worker.1]: Starting process with command `yarn test-worker`
2021-11-11T17:27:23.532721+00:00 heroku[test-worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-11-11T17:27:24.083102+00:00 app[test-worker.1]: yarn run v1.22.17
2021-11-11T17:27:24.133902+00:00 app[test-worker.1]: $ node lib/test-worker/src/index.js
2021-11-11T17:27:24.192198+00:00 app[test-worker.1]: starting
2021-11-11T17:27:24.192700+00:00 app[test-worker.1]: ping
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of Heroku support, we were able to figure out that the reason is using `yarn`. Apparently, `yarn` is not waiting for child processes to gracefully shut down. See https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4667.

The solution is to not use `yarn` in your `Procfile` and to use `node` directly.